# Can I use real cars in my racing game?(Yeah,I know)

Tags: racing

I know this was asked a million times.I know I can't use real car names or badges,but what about body design? I saw a lot of games with real body designs.My other question is about the engine names:VR6,TFSI,1/2JZ etc.can I use them? And if I can use body designs,does that apply to rims too? My last question is that is it legal to use words like WRC,WTCC,NASCAR,F1,LMP,GT3 etc.?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question that a lawyer could answer.

Comment: Also, probably covered here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14460/is-it-legal-to-use-car-manufacturers-names-in-a-game

Comment: I agree, it's a duplicate question. But besides that, if it's something that could be considered a brand name or trademark (or definitely is), stay away, unless you have explicit permission. You don't need a lawyer for that.